# How to use rollup and cost_optimize parameters to calculate cost optimized routes using Routing API?

Tags: here-api

as stated in Here Maps Fleet Telematics documentation, under Toll Cost & Cost Optimized Routes section, by specifying one or both of parameters rollup and cost_optimize, one can calculate route using Routing API instead of Fleet Telematics API.

However, those parameters are not specified in API reference and when I use them server responds with 400 error and message shown in picture.

[400 Bad Request response when using beforementioned parameters][1]

How do I use those parameters in request and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this request which gives proper response with both the parameters i.e **&rollups and &cost_customise**.

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={API_KEY}&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&driver_cost=10&waypoint0=50.10992,8.69030&waypoint1=50.00658,8.29096&cost_optimize=true&rollups =none,tollsys,country,total
```